# Windows 8 UAC disabled + neo4j + tomcat 7 - no permission to write to disk?

Tags: java, windows-8, neo4j, tomcat7

I have an Eclipse Kepler installation. I have created a new Dynamic Web Project, and imported the neo4j's project sources, including dependencies by hand. The neo4j project works fine on its own. But when I try to use it with tomcat 7 I get an error. I suspect it cannot write to disk but it gives me a `ClassNotFoundException` for the RelationshipType.

I have also disabled UAC on my Windows 8 machine. Any ideas? I am going crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like stuff isn't in the classpath for the classnotfound error. Do you have the required JARs in tomcat's lib?

Comment: Yes, i do. I am quite sure. When deleting the import, and hitting control + shift + o, it correctly writes the imports.

Comment: But that doesn't mean tomcat actually has the jars in its classpath.

Comment: Yes, it does not. And you are a genius. Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you know how i can add them to the server that is started by eclipse?

Comment: Or can i embed them in the generated war file?

Comment: Either way (add them to the eclipse server or embed, but the war file will be a lot bigger if you embed them). This might help:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/475513/vc/Tomcat-server-lib-location-running